# read multiple files in jar

Tags: java, jar

I want to read multiple files in my jar file. But it doesn't work. It only reads one file and stops. I don't really understand how `Inputstream` and `Bufferedreader` works. That part of code is borrowed from another post.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numList; i++) { // numList is number of file I want to read
     int fileNum = i + 1;
     String fileaddress = "List" + fileNum + ".txt";
     //All the files have name like "List1.txt", "List2.txt", etc
     InputStream configStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileaddress);
     BufferedReader wordReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(configStream, "UTF-8"));
     //the following is to store values in the line in an String array
     //add the array to an ArrayList called masterList
     String[] line;
     while((line = wordReader.readLine().split(": ")) != null){
     masterList.add(line);
}
```

Comment: Is the code throwing any exception, or is it just silently "failing"?

Comment: Also, is there any reason why you are not starting at `1`, than going to `<= numList`?  That way you don't need to store a variable `fileNum` and just reference `i`.

Comment: What is the value of `numList`? If this is 1 then it will stop after the first read.

Comment: Does your  code  have try/catch/finally?  Have you  read  the  java io  tutorials? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/

Comment: While it may not necessarily be the issue, I strongly advise closing the `BufferedReader` and the `InputStream` at the end of the loop body by wrapping the while loop in a `try` block and putting the following in the `finally` block: `wordReader.close();` and `configStream.close()`.

Comment: No exception. It just reads one. Is it supposed to be ok? I do have try catch. NumList is 2.